# How to set C# application to accept Command Line Parameters?

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments

I have created a C# command line application that creates a few reports automatically for my client.  However, even though they use 95% of the same code I would like to split them in to different processes. I am using Windows task scheduler to run them.  How do I set up the C# application to accept Command line parameters upon runtime?

I cannot find any explanation of this on the internet.

Comment: "I cannot find any explanation of this on the internet. " -- then you must not have tried hard enough.  This is basic basic stuff.  Very well documented.  Check MSDN.

Comment: Other than `static void Main(string[] args)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All command line parameters are passed to your application through `string[] args` parameter.
 The code below shows an example:

```
using System.Linq;

namespace MyApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Contains("/REPORT1"))
            {
                /* Do something */
            }
            else if (args.Contains("/REPORT2"))
            {
                /* Do something */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in command prompt just use:

```
C:\MyApp\MyApp.exe /REPORT1
```

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3.aspx)

The below snippet will print the number of parameters passed from the command line... `string[] args` contains the parameter values...

```
class TestClass
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Display the number of command line arguments:
        System.Console.WriteLine(args.Length);
    }
}
```